# QT Creator can not remote run and debugging on i.Mx6 (buildroot)

Tags: qt, qt-creator, buildroot, imx6

Using Qt Creator 4.0.2 base on Qt 5.7.0, my app name is `test`

Board : i.M6Q with buildroot (Qt 5.9)

## Questions:

### A. When I run qt app show this error

```
EGL library doesn't support Emulator extensions 
Aborted
Application finished with exit code 134.
```

But I can run qt app in board using ./test, and it shows normally

### B. And When I start debugging show this error

```
The GDB process terminated unexpectedly (exit code 1)
```

How to fix these errors?

## The following is what I have set up:

1. `test.pro`

   ```
   QT += core gui
   greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
   TARGET = test
   TEMPLATE = app
   SOURCES += main.cpp\
   mainwindow.cpp
   HEADERS  += mainwindow.h
   FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

   target.path = /root/test
   INSTALLS += target
   ```
2. Tools > Options > Build & Run > Compilers

   Name : `imx6 buildroot GCC`

   ```
   buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-g++
   ```
3. Tools > Options > Build & Run > Debuggers

   Name : `IMX6 buildroot gdb`

   ```
   buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/arm-buildroot-linux-uclibcgnueabihf-gdb
   ```
4. Tools > Options > Build & Run > Qt Versions

   Version Name : `Qt %{Qt:Version} (buildroot)`

   ```
   buildroot/output/host/usr/bin/qmake
   ```
5. Tools > Options > Build & Run > Kits [look like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eajs9.jpg)
6. Tools > Options > Devices:

   ```
   Device test finished successfully.
   ```
7. This is my `main.cpp`

   ```
   #include "mainwindow.h"
   #include <QApplication>
   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       QApplication a(argc, argv);
       MainWindow w;
       w.show();

       return a.exec();
   }
   ```

Comment: Please do not link to images of error messages; add the text to your question instead.

Comment: @Murphy thanks for your advice, I edited the error messages into text mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a reported [Qt BUG](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-61156)
The problem is that the build system does not select the correct eglfs backend

The solution is to export:

`QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=eglfs_viv` before running Qt apps, or

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=none
```

Comment: When I run today, it shows another error which is " line 1: syntax error: unexpected ";;" ". And it can not run qt app in board normally.

Comment: And at 'Gerneral Messages' it shows 'buildroot/output/host/mkspecs/features/qmake_use.prf(6): 'take_first' is not a recognized replace function.
Project ERROR: Library '' is not defined.'

Comment: @JuliaDing These seems new code errors not related to this post. you can close this post and ask new one with enough details

Comment: I serach for "eglfs_viv", then I found out I don't have graphics acceleration on my board for qt app running with "eglfs_viv".            

     When I Enter '# CinematicExperience-demo -platform eglfs', 
it will show 'qt.qpa.egldeviceintegration: Failed to load EGL device integration "eglfs_viv"'. But CinematicExperience-demo run normally?     !
I will try to turn on graphics acceleration on i.Mx6, then try your answer again. if it works I will check yoour answer, thanks.

Comment: Originally, I run on VMware Ubuntu. When I not using VMware, the qt app remote run and debugging successfully.