# Can't run Qt application o 32-bit Yocto build with eglfs

Tags: qt, yocto, raspberry-pi4

I have built a Yocto image with the following configuration

```
# Architecture of the host machine
SDKMACHINE ?= "x86_64"

# Extra image configuration defaults
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES = "debug-tweaks ssh-server-openssh"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "openssh-sftp openssh-sftp-server"
INIT_MANAGER = "systemd"
INHERIT += "rm_work"

# Extra packages

LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST = "commercial"


DISTRO_FEATURES:remove = " \
  x11 \
  directfb \
  vulkan \
  wayland \
  "

DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " \
  alsa \
  opengl \
  gles2 \
"

IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " \
  coreutils \
  qtbase-plugins \
  qtbase-tools \
  qtdeclarative \
  qtdeclarative-plugins \
  qtdeclarative-qmlplugins \
  qtdeclarative-tools \
  qtimageformats-plugins \
  qtmultimedia \
  qtmultimedia-plugins \
  qtmultimedia-qmlplugins \
  qtquickcontrols2 \
  qtquicktimeline \
  qtscript \
  qtsvg \
  qtsvg-plugins \
  qtsystems \
  qtsystems-qmlplugins \
  qtsystems-tools \
  rsync \
"

PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qtbase = " \
  eglfs \
  fontconfig \
  gles2 \
  libpng \
  jpeg \
  libs \
  widgets \
  "

# Image file system types to package
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "rpi-sdimg"

# Package management configuration
PACKAGE_CLASSES = "package_ipk"


MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi4"
DISTRO ??= "poky"
BBMULTICONFIG ?= ""
```

I could successfully build and generate and SDK. I can build the Qt app and deploy it to the device.

I set

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=eglfs
DISPLAY=:0
```

but I get the error

```
EGL library doesn't support Emulator extensions
Aborted
```

The error looks similar to

[QT Creator can not remote run and debugging on i.Mx6 (buildroot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898605/qt-creator-can-not-remote-run-and-debugging-on-i-mx6-buildroot/48905744)

but since the Pi doesn't have a Vivante driver, I wouldn't know what to pass. I tried to search for integrations

```
$ find / -name "*egl*"
/usr/lib/plugins/video/videonode/libeglvideonode.so
/usr/lib/plugins/videoeglvideonode
/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations
/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-emu-integration.so
/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-integration.so
/usr/lib/plugins/egldeviceintegrations/libqeglfs-kms-egldevice-integration.so
/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so
/usr/lib/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so
```

but `eglfs-kms` or all other combinations I have tried, don't work.

If I try

```
QT_QPA_EGLFS_INTEGRATION=none
```

I get

```
Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi.
To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters).
Cannot find EGLConfig, returning null config
EGL Error : Could not create the egl surface: error = 0x300b
```

Comment: Did you try set "export QT_QPA_EGLFS_FB=/dev/fbX"? You can try also set framebuffer to 16 or 32 bpp instead of 24.
"echo 32 > /sys/class/graphics/fbX/bits_per_pixel" Where X in fbX is your framebuffer number.

Comment: @kluszon Hey, thank you. I just tried that, but it doesn't do the trick unfortunately